# How to exclude most dissimilar value of set in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, similarity

I have a df looking like this but larger:

```
values <- c(22,16,23,15,14.5,19)
groups <- rep(c("a","b"), each = 3)
df <- data.frame(groups, values)
```

I have between 1-3 values per group (in the example 3 values for group a and 3 values for group b). I now want to exclude the most dissimilar value from each group.
In this example I would want to exclude a 16 and b 19.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you define _most dissimilar_?

Comment: Filter by groups find the difference between each individual values and delete the one which has maximum or minimum value in average. For something like your example, but again dissimilarity can have any form.

Comment: What happens when you have 2 values? Both are equally dissimilar, no?

Comment: Hi, thank you - I have standard deviation values for each group and I am looking to remove the value that will decrease the standard deviation - one could call it an outlier too.

Comment: RE 1 or 2 values - yes, for those I do not mean to remove any just wanted to mention this so the code would not crash if that scenario was encountered - but I can add that myself - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for **one** value to discard, you can remove the observation that has the highest distance from the mean value per group:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(groups) %>% 
  mutate(dist = abs(values - mean(values))) %>% 
  filter(dist != max(dist))

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   groups [2]
  groups values  dist
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        22    1.67
2 a        23    2.67
3 b        15    1.17
4 b        14.5  1.67
```